# Problem connecting to Steamworks via Facepunch.Steamworks

Tags: unity, steam

I'm using Facepunch.Steamworks (https://github.com/Facepunch/Facepunch.Steamworks) to connect my Unity game to Steam. The login seems to work fine. The `board` object is an FP class, and `AddScore` is a call to the library to send the score to Steam.

I have the boards set up on Steam, and they come out with `IsValid == true`. Here are the output and the code. The boards currently have no data in them, so I don't think it's because the score isn't beating an existing one.

> ```
> xxxxxxxx
> Standard-Normal
> True
> Fail
> ```

```
public void SubmitScore(Globals.ApplicationMode mode, Globals.SkillLevels skillLevel, int score)
{
    int index = GetLeaderboardIndex(mode, skillLevel);
    if(index == -1 || !IsSteamPlatform())
    {
        return;
    }
    Leaderboard board = m_leaderboards[index];
    Debug.Log("xxxxxxxx");
    Debug.Log(board.Name);
    Debug.Log(board.IsValid);
    board.AddScore(true, score, null, AddScoreSuccessCallback, AddScoreFailureCallback);
}

private void AddScoreSuccessCallback(Leaderboard.AddScoreResult result)
{
    Debug.Log(result.Score);
}

private void AddScoreFailureCallback(Facepunch.Steamworks.Callbacks.Result result)
{
    Debug.Log(result.ToString());
}
```

Here's a shot of the leaderboards on the Steam control panel. They seem in order; their "Writes" attributes are false so that the client can submit to them directly.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it with board.AddScore(false, ...) ? From the documentation, it looks like as long as that's true, it will fail if it doesn't beat an existing score. Not having a score may be the problem depending on how they implemented that condition.

Comment: Good idea; didn't seem to change anything. I reverified that the `board` is ok; I tried getting it from Steam with the wrong name, and got a null board, as expected. There's a slight delay before it prints "Fail", so I'm pretty sure it's hitting the server. I've added a shot of the Steam tables; they also appear to be configured correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must fetch the scores before you can submit.

```
foreach(Leaderboard board in m_leaderboards)
{
    board.FetchScores(Leaderboard.RequestType.Global, 0, 10);
}
```

After executing the  above code, submissions work fine.